# App crashes when I try to reference the firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm very new with Swift and Firebase. My current project is in Xcode 8. I followed a few tutorials and now I'm stuck. I might have found the problem. When I try to reference the database, the app crashes. That happens at the following line:

```
var ref = Firebase.Database().reference()
```

I have tried many things like adding the following lines of code:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

But that didn't work. I also tried to remove a few files and make a new podfile and did the same thing as before with the Terminal. In my Podfile I have the following things:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        var ref = Firebase.Database().reference()

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

        return true
    }
```

Maybe it's a stupid question but I'm stuck.

Comment: You need to update your question (don't post a comment) with the complete and exact error message.

Comment: To capture the error message (that rmaddy is asking for), right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use the code below as you don't need to call `Firebase.Database`:

```
let reference = Database.database().reference()
```

You'll want to not do anything like what you're trying to do, inside your AppDelegate file. You'll want to do this inside you controller classes. For example, your default ViewController class that XCode creates for you. Any questions, let me know. We've all been there!

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! 
I'm working in different classes but just to make it easy to explain I have pasted that line of code into the AppDelegate.

Comment: Hi @daniel-dramond I have the same issue, but in my first view controller. The strange thing, is that it worked when I'm in Xcode and Run directly. But when deploy to Apple Store, it crash.